# C - Parameter Name Omitted?

Tags: c, windows, macos, terminal, sublimetext3

So progressing with class work, learning C

I had decided to progressivly put in functions as per my brief from my class work as shown below for context, in an attempt to troubleshoot code piece by piece:

[Structure Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIppM.png)

[Functions Brief](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHm83.png)

Psuedocode ive been told to follow:

```
use #define SIZE 3
function : main
-----------------------
Local variables:
- emp_array (an array of 3 employee detail values)
- i (an integer used as the index for the arrays)
- char str[20] to read in name of employee for search
-----------------------
1: call read_all_employee, passing in emp_array and SIZE
2: Print the message ‘Employee details are’
3: call print_all_employee, passing in emp_array and SIZE
4: Print 'Total : ', employee_total_salary (emp_array, SIZE)
5: Print the message '—Employee with the largest salary is --'
6: Store in i, the search_largest_salary_index passing in emp_array and SIZE
7: Call print_employee, passing in emp_array at index i
8: Print the message '— Enter employee name for the search--'
9: read in the name in str array
10: Store in i, the search_an_employee_salary passing in emp_array, SIZE and str
11: if something was found
12: Print the message 'The salary of xxxx is xxxx’
13: else
14: Print the message "Array does not contain an employee named xxxx"
15: Print the message '—Employee details in reverse order are --'
16: Loop i starting from 2 to 0 for each index of emp_array
17: Call print_employee, passing in emp_array at index i
```

But compiling the program, i keep coming across the errors 'Parameter Name Omitted' for every function where size is declared after `#define size 3` is inserted,  and ')' name expected

This is the code i have so far written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 3

struct employee{
    char name[20];
    int emp_id;
    float salary;
};

struct employee read_employee(){
    struct employee r_employee;
    printf("Enter Employee Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &r_employee.name);
    printf("Enter ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &r_employee.emp_id);
    printf("Enter Salary: ");
    scanf("%f", &r_employee.salary);

    while (r_employee.salary < 0){
        printf("This is not a valid price, enter again\n");
        scanf("%f", &r_employee.salary);
        }
    return r_employee;
}

struct employee read_all_employee(struct employee emp_array[], int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        emp_array[i] = read_employee();
    }
}

void print_employee(struct employee employee_data){
    printf("%s(%d): %f\n", employee_data.name, employee_data.emp_id, employee_data.salary);
    if (employee_data.salary > 5000)
    {
        printf("Level A\n");
    }
    if (employee_data.salary < 4000)
    {
        printf("Level B\n");
    }
}

float employee_total_salary(struct employee emp_array[], int size){
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + employee_array[i].salary;
    }
    return sum;
}

int employee_index_search(struct employee emp_array[], int id, int size){
    int i;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (employee_array[i].emp_id == id)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(){
    struct employee emp_array[3];
    int i;
    char str[20];

    printf("Line 1:\n");
    read_all_employee(emp_array, size);
    printf("Employee Details are:\n");
return 0;
}
```

Could someone please correct my code so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Parameter Name Omitted

means, the compiler doesn't see a parameter name where it expects...

This is because you can't use `define` and a parameter name with the same name. When writing `#define size 3` the pre-processor replaces each `size` it sees in the code with `3` and then, when you call a function with parameter `size`, instead of `struct employee read_all_employee(..., int size)`, you get `struct employee read_all_employee(..., int 3)`, resulting in an argument of type `int` with no valid name *('3' is not a valid name)*.

I would recommend using a `define` with CAPS, or with some unique name, so you won't get confused, like `SIZE` or just keep in mind that you have `size` symbol and use other parameter names in your function, such as `input_size`